# Centos 6.4 Installed in System X3750 M4 IBM Server

Tags: tomcat, performance-tuning, configuration

We have installed Centos 6.4 in System X3750 M4 IBM Server. But the server is not showing the performance of at-least a normal Desktop Configuration. We haven't done any performance tuning in the Server.

Soon after completing the installation we checked the system monitor in the system, and there it shows total 32 CPUs and only about 3 CPUs have load, others are in idle mode.

## Our System Configuration is:

IBM System x3750 M4 Server

300GB * 4 HDD

32GB RAM

2 Quad Core * 4 ProcessorsNos = 32 CPUs

Intel Xeon Processor

### Partition:

RAID 1

2 HDDs in one RAID.

## MANUAL PARTITION

```
/dev/sda6              58G  629M   55G   2% /
tmpfs                  16G  664K   16G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2             485M   37M  424M   8% /boot
/dev/sda1             200M  260K  200M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda5              68G  878M   64G   2% /home
/dev/sda7              29G  172M   28G   1% /opt
/dev/sda8              29G  188M   28G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda9              29G  3.9G   24G  15% /usr
/dev/sdb1             274G  773M  260G   1% /var
```

Centos 6.4 Server

java version "1.7.0_25"

Database : mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

JBOSS 6 Application Server

## Apache Tomcat 7.14

What all Basic configuration must be done in the Centos 6.4 to achieve a good performance?

We are newbies in this field , i.e in server configuration and all. So please help us.

Thanks in advance.

Nevin Alex.

Comment: What does "at-least a normal Desktop Configuration" mean? Do you have a performance baseline? Where are your metrics? What are you measuring? What historical data do you have for those metrics on your application’s previous server. Also please read [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), [professional capacity](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) and [How can I ask better questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault).

Comment: After the installation of Centos 6.4 in the specified server in my previous post; while I am taking any application like gedit or konqueror the application hangs and a I feel a slowness in the whole system. This will be more when I am taking the System Monitor Tool. Please help me in sorting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open a terminal window and issue this command: top -b -n1 > /root/topcmd, this will save the output of top to the file /root/topcmd, open it with a text editor and copy its contents here to find out whats going on. Probably some program or service is missbehaving

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel J . Here is the output: upto 300000 Lines

top - 21:21:50 up  2:06,  5 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.07, 0.10
Tasks: 828 total,   1 running, 827 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.6%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32688948k total, 10546356k used, 22142592k free,    90116k buffers
Swap: 65535992k total,        0k used, 65535992k free,  1759772k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 3547 root      20   0  178m  61m  11m S  3.4  0.2   4:56.71 Xorg
16003 root      20   0 15548 1800  888 R  3.4  0.0   0:00.09 top
   37 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  1.7  0.0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/8
    1 root      20   0 19228 1512 1220 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.17 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.45 migration/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/1
   10 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1
   11 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2
   12 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/2
   14 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/2
   15 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/3
   16 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/3
   17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/3
   18 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/3
   19 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/4
   20 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/4
   21 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/4
   22 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/4
   23 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/5
   24 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/5
   25 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/5
   26 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/5
   27 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/6
   28 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/6
   29 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/6
   30 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/6
   31 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/7
   32 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/7
   33 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/7
   34 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/7
   35 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 migration/8
   36 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/8
   38 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/8
   39 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/9
   40 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/9
   41 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 ksoftirqd/9
   42 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/9
   43 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/10
   44 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/10
   45 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/10
   46 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/10
   47 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/11
   48 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/11
   49 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/11
   50 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/11
   51 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/12
   52 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/12
   53 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/12
   54 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/12
   55 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/13
   56 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/13
   57 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/13
   58 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/13
   59 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/14
   60 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/14
   61 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/14
   62 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/14
   63 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/15
   64 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/15
   65 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/15
   66 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/15
   67 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/16
   68 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/16
   69 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/16
   70 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/16
   71 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/17
   72 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/17
   73 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/17
   74 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/17
   75 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/18
   76 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/18
   77 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/18
   78 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/18
   79 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/19
   80 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/19
   81 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/19
   82 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/19
   83 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/20
   84 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/20
   85 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/20
   86 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/20
   87 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/21
   88 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/21
   89 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/21
   90 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/21
   91 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/22
   92 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/22
   93 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/22
   94 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/22
   95 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/23
   96 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/23
   97 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/23
   98 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/23
   99 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.08 migration/24
  100 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/24
  101 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/24
  102 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/24
  103 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/25
  104 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/25
  105 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/25
  106 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/25
  107 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/26
  108 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/26
  109 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/26
  110 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/26
  111 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/27
  112 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/27
  113 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/27
  114 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/27
  115 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/28
  116 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/28
  117 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/28
  118 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/28
  119 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/29
  120 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/29
  121 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/29
  122 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/29
  123 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/30
  124 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/30
  125 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/30
  126 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/30
  127 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/31
  128 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/31
  129 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/31
  130 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/31
  131 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.44 events/0
  132 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.18 events/1
  133 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.17 events/2
  134 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.18 events/3
  135 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.20 events/4
  136 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.22 events/5
  137 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.18 events/6
  138 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.18 events/7
  139 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.29 events/8
  140 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.18 events/9
  141 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.17 events/10
  142 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.16 events/11
  143 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.18 events/12
  144 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.20 events/13
  145 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.21 events/14
  146 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.21 events/15
  147 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.21 events/16
  148 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.17 events/17
  149 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.16 events/18
  150 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.17 events/19
  151 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.16 events/20
  152 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.22 events/21
  153 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.20 events/22
  154 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.25 events/23
  155 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.20 events/24
  156 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.18 events/25
  157 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.17 events/26
  158 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.16 events/27
  159 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.19 events/28
  160 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.18

Comment: Dear J Daniel I have posted the output as you have told in your post.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.